# After change to org-mode 9.1.13, TAB not work when put after `<s`

Tags: org-mode

Usually, `TAB` after `<s` expand to `#+BEGIN_SRC` in org-mode, but today I updated my org to version 9.1.13, and `TAB` not work this way any more.

I don't know where to start to figure this out, but I `C-h k TAB` after `<s` and the help message is like this:

> runs the command org-cycle, which is an interactive autoloaded
>   compiled Lisp function in `org.el'.
>
> It is bound to `tab`, `TAB`, `menu-bar` `Tbl` `Next Field`, `menu-bar`
>   `Org` `Show/Hide` `Cycle Visibility`.
>
> (org-cycle &optional ARG)
>
> For more information check the manuals.
>
> TAB-action and visibility cycling for Org mode.
>
> This is the command invoked in Org mode by the ‘TAB’ key.  Its main
>   purpose is outline visibility cycling, but it also invokes other
>   actions in special contexts.
>
> When this function is called with a ‘C-u’ prefix, rotate the entire
>   buffer through 3 states (global cycling)
>     1. OVERVIEW: Show only top-level headlines.
>     2. CONTENTS: Show all headlines of all levels, but no body text.
>     3. SHOW ALL: Show everything.
>
> With a ‘C-u C-u’ prefix argument, switch to the startup visibility,
>   determined by the variable ‘org-startup-folded’, and by any VISIBILITY
>   properties in the buffer.
>
> With a ‘C-u C-u C-u’ prefix argument, show the entire buffer,
>   including any drawers.
>
> When inside a table, re-align the table and move to the next field.
>
> When point is at the beginning of a headline, rotate the subtree
>   started by this line through 3 different states (local cycling)
>     1. FOLDED:   Only the main headline is shown.
>     2. CHILDREN: The main headline and the direct children are shown.
>                  From this state, you can move to one of the children
>                  and zoom in further.
>     3. SUBTREE:  Show the entire subtree, including body text. If there is no subtree, switch directly from CHILDREN to FOLDED.
>
> When point is at the beginning of an empty headline and the variable
>   ‘org-cycle-level-after-item/entry-creation’ is set, cycle the level of
>   the headline by demoting and promoting it to likely levels.  This
>   speeds up creation document structure by pressing ‘TAB’ once or
>   several times right after creating a new headline.
>
> When there is a numeric prefix, go up to a heading with level ARG, do
>   a ‘show-subtree’ and return to the previous cursor position.  If ARG
>   is negative, go up that many levels.
>
> When point is not at the beginning of a headline, execute the global
>   binding for ‘TAB’, which is re-indenting the line.  See the option
>   ‘org-cycle-emulate-tab’ for details.
>
> As a special case, if point is at the beginning of the buffer and
>   there is no headline in line 1, this function will act as if called
>   with prefix arg (‘C-u TAB’, same as ‘S-TAB’) also when called without
>   prefix arg, but only if the variable ‘org-cycle-global-at-bob’ is t.
>
> [back]

Can you help me with where should I start to figure the problem out?

Comment: Try starting emacs with no init file `emacs -q`, load (with `M-x load-file` or anything like that) just the new version of `org-mode` and check if the problem persists. If that isn't the case, the problem is related to your config.

Comment: It's worth running `org-version` to check that you are actually using v9.1.3.  If you are, then `<s Tab` should work.  If you're running a more recent, developmental version of Org, expansion won't work because easy templates were removed in c04e357f3 (Replace easy templates with org-insert-structure-template, 2017-11-05).

Comment: Thank you very much, @KyleMeyer . I've made a mistake but I am running v9.1.13, that is exactly because of what you said.

Comment: [Link to commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/c04e357f3). Note that the old functionality is/will be mostly re-implemented with [`org-tempo`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org-tempo.el). (See also [this message](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-12/msg00414.html) on the mailing list very briefly describing `org-tempo` and the [start](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-09/msg00038.html) of the long thread spanning several months where the changes were discussed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to add to the answer of [m43cap](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/16762/m43cap):

`<s` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

works in Orgmode 9.2 and later if you activate the checkbox for `org-tempo` of the customization option `org-modules`.

You get to that customization option through the menu item `Options -> Customize Emacs -> Specific Option ...`, input of the option name `org-modules`, and <kbd>RET</kbd>. Tab-completion is possible during the input of the option name.

Alternatively you can input <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-modules` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Tab-completion is possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
<s TAB
```

still works at least since org-mode version 9.1.0. In org-mode version 9.2.4 (and maybe earlier) it might be better to use

```
M-x org-insert-structure-template
```

which should be bound to C-c C-,

Answer (score 0):

[This github issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11798) explains the source of the issue.

Currently

```
C-c C-, s
```

Will insert a source code block.  Note that there are a suite of other templates that can be inserted this way by choosing a letter other than `s`.  At first I really didn't like this change but I have gotten used to it, it takes about the same amount of effort as `<s TAB` for me but has the added benefit of showing what other templates are available in a popup menu.

Also, if you feel so inclined or use custom blocks you can hit

```
C-c C-, TAB
```

which pops up a mini-buffer and lets you type in a custom block name.

Eg.

```
C-c C-, TAB myBlock

---yields---

 #+begin_myBlock 
 #+end_myBlock
```